# Can't create component in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new in Angular2, I try create new Component but have error

```
Argument of type '{ selecor: string; templateUrl: string; }' is not assignable 
to parametof type 'Component'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'selecor' does not  
exist in type 'Component'.enter code here.
```

This is code for component.

```
Import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
   selecor: 'app-server',
   templateUrl: './server.component.html'
})
export class ServerComponent {}
```

And this is snippet code in app.module.ts

```
import { ServerComponent } from './server/server.component';
@NgModule({
declarations: [
  AppComponent,
  ServerComponent
],
```

Comment: @Sajeetharan I will do it, per 5 minutes. Now I have blocked this option.

Comment: I would suggest using ng cli to make your life easier

Comment: If you use Angular Cli (https://cli.angular.io/) you can get rid of this kind of typos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be **`selector`** instead of **`selecor`**,

```
@Component({
   selector : 'app-server',
   templateUrl: './server.component.html'
})
```

Comment: You were faster :)